# Quartz.net StartNow() ignored with DailyAtHourAndMinute()

Tags: quartz.net

`DailyAtHourAndMinute()` works , but why is `StartNow()` ignored?

```
TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("engineTriggerII", engineGroup).StartNow().WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(0, 0)).Build();
```

version 2.3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour.

You're telling your trigger to fire every day at midnight so it will never fire now ... unless you're running it at midnight.

I guess you'll have to create 2 triggers to achieve what you want.

You can check when the trigger is scheduled to run using this code:

```
private static void GetNextXFireTimes(ITrigger trigger, int counts)
{
    var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

    for (int i = 0; i < (counts-1); i++)
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime());

        dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
    }
}
```

and you can call it after you've scheduled your job:

```
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
GetNextXFireTimes(trigger, 100);
```

and you should see something like this:

```
18/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
19/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
20/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
21/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
22/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
23/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
24/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
25/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
26/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
27/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
28/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
29/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
30/09/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
01/10/2015 00:00:00 +01:00
```